# Find correspondent row in array

Tags: microsoft-excel, array, range

I've a product's list containing each product's weight. I've another table with ranges of weights, and each range has a different storage cost.

I'd like to have a formula that identifies in which range is each product and get the correspondent storage cost.

Here's what I have (top: product's list, bottom: storage price per range):

[image]

Any thought on how do I do it??

Best

Gabriel

Answer (score 1):

If you can lay out the data as such:

[image]

.. so that storage cost is the third column instead of the first, you can use this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($E2,$A$12:$C$16,3,TRUE)
```

Where the first argument is the value you're looking up, the second argument is the entire range for your lookup (not including headers), the third argument is the column of your table to get the data from, and the last argument specifies it's searching within a range.

Also note that your values for the kg's must be *formatted* this way and **not** actually contain the string "KG" as a value. For example, I've formatted them as such:

[image]

---

**Edit:** If you wish to keep the data in the same layout, you can use this instead:

```
=INDEX($A$12:$A$16,MATCH(E2,$B$12:$B$16,1))
```

A little less readable but not as bad as I initially started. Note you don't actually need the `Weight to:` column, this only needs to check it's *above* the `Weight from:` column

Comment: with the original setup formula would be combination of `MATCH` and `INDEX`

Comment: @MátéJuhász I started doing that and it got a bit messy quite quickly. Will post a version of that if the OP can't change the data layout :)

Comment: @MátéJuhász I added it anyway, it wasn't quite as untidy as I originally thought :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(E2<=$C$12,$A$12,IF(E2<=$C$13,$A$13,IF(E2<=$C$14,$A$14,IF(E2<=$C$15,$A$15,IF(E2<=$C$16,$A$16)))))
```

to understand the logic behind it I'll show how it works:

```
IF(E2<=$C$12
    $A$12
ELSE
    IF(E2<=$C$13
       $A$13
    ELSE
        IF(E2<=$C$14
          $A$14
        ELSE
            IF(E2<=$C$15
               $A$15
            ELSE
                IF(E2<=$C$16
                   $A$16
                END IF
            END IF
        END IF
    END IF
END IF
```

It is uglier and messier than @Jonno's answer but when you understand its logic it is very straightforward.